# In unix, how can I manipulate a textfile to ensure value in column 3 is smaller than value in column 4?

Tags: unix, awk

I want to look through a textfile, row by row, and switch columns 3 and 4 if the value in column 3 is greater than the value in column 4.

For example:

I want to sort from this:

```
890     890     3300    1767    4432P1
2135    2135    3300    1944    
2135    2135    3300    1944
890     890     1772    4000    4448P1
2135    2135    3189    4000
```

to this:

```
890     890     1767    3300    4432P1
2135    2135    1944    3300    
2135    2135    1944    3300    
890     890     1772    4000    4448P1
2135    2135    3189    4000
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '$3>$4{t=$4;$4=$3;$3=t}1' file | column -t
890   890   1767  3300  4432P1
2135  2135  1944  3300
2135  2135  1944  3300
890   890   1772  4000  4448P1
2135  2135  3189  4000
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use perl:

```
perl -anE '@F[2,3] = sort {$a <=> $b} @F[2,3]; say "@F"'
```

That will destroy the original spacing. You might want to pipe into `column -t` to make it pretty. If, on the other hand, you want tab-separated output, then do `say join "\t", @F`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ awk '{if($3>$4){tmp=$3;$3=$4;$4=tmp;print}else print}' file | column -t
```

**Output:**

```
890   890   1767  3300  4432P1
2135  2135  1944  3300
2135  2135  1944  3300
890   890   1772  4000  4448P1
2135  2135  3189  4000
```